# kafka-streams 2.5.0 does not support Named on reduce?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

---

Hi,
I am needing to give a custom name to the internal/intermediate topics created in kafka-streams.

However, only the "*repartitioned" topics get renamed, while the "*aggregate*" ones are not renamed.

It looks as if kafka-streams 2.5.0 does not support Named on reduce?

I configured it but it does not take it..the grouped ones takes the named & see the repartitioned topics with that name but the reduced does not take that name.

I would need in order to be able to demo nicely Azkarra streams when browsing the state stores to query.

---

Update:
Hello kafka community,
I understand, the Named argument i used is used to config used to name the processor in the topology,
But is there any way I can give a custom, more readable name to an intermediate topic like kstream-aggregate-... ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to name all processors/stores/topics.

However, it's not always clear how the API works -- in fact, some
`Named` parameters "overlap". It's a know issue and not well documented.
We need to fix this at some point.

If you want to name a changelog topic, you can name the corresponding
store, via `Materialized`, and the store name will be reused for the
changelog topic.

If you want to name a repartition topic, you can pass a name via the
`Grouped` parameter of `groupBy()` or `groupByKey()`.